# Accessing redux store to get a stream of data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to show a loading bar when the user uploads a PSD file based on upload progress.

Example: 
[image]

I am dispatching an action when the file starts uploading & the store is getting updated accordingly.

```
  const postFormData = ({ url, data, files }) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    store.dispatch({ type: START_FILE_UPLOAD });

    const formData = new FormData();
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => formData.set(key, data[key]));
    Object.keys(files)
      .map((key) => {
        const { file, filename } = files[key];
        return { key, file, filename };
      })
      .forEach(({ key, file, filename }) => formData.set(key, file, filename));

    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('POST', url);
    request.upload.addEventListener('progress', ({ lengthComputable, loaded, total }) => {
      if (lengthComputable) {
        const feedData = { loaded, total };
        store.dispatch({ type: START_FILE_UPLOAD, payload: feedData });
      }
    });
    request.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
      store.dispatch({ type: END_FILE_UPLOAD });
      resolve(event);
    });
    request.addEventListener('error', (event) => {
      store.dispatch({ type: END_FILE_UPLOAD });
      reject(event);
    });
    request.send(formData);
  });
```

Here's the store updating:

[image]

But I can't get the `loaded` & `loading` state from the store inside the component.

How can I access the stream of data from the store as it gets updated, inside the component?

Comment: subscribe to store using selector.

Comment: @Abhishek Can you please share some code or a link?

Comment: just see this: `
https://redux.js.org/api/store
`

Comment: Are you using react-redux ?

Comment: @Abhishek Yes, I am

Comment: Sry, I can't help here. I mostly worked with angular redux ngRx not with react.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [react-redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux), use its connect method to connect your component to the store

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Sample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.loading}: {this.props.loaded}</div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  loading: state.creations.loading,
  loaded: state.creations.loaded,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Sample);
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Inside the component, I've tried the same you suggested & also tried life cycle method like getDerivedStateFromProps

Comment: If you'll show us the component where you used `connect`, and tell us what happened, perhaps we can help diagnose why it wasn't working.